# How to create a Tableau Calculated Field?

Tags: sql, tableau-api

I am creating a workbook involving customers and associated products. I would only like to show customers that are `Active`. The field `Status` will have this value in it.

So, I want to create a calculated field filter item to say if the `Status` field reads `Active`, then show those and this is what I have so far.

```
IF Status = 'Active' THEN
ELSE
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simpler than that. Just drag 'Status' Field to the Filters box in the worksheet, and select 'Active'.

It's very very basic stuff, please read the basic tutorials or watch the tutorial videos. This one should be explained here http://www.tableausoftware.com/learn/tutorials/on-demand/filtering-conditions-0

Watch the others too